# Lucene.Net fuzzy search speed

Tags: c#, performance, search, lucene, lucene.net

Sorry for the concern, but I hope to get any help from Lucene-experienced people.

Now we use in our application Lucene.Net 3.0.3 to index and search by ~2.500.000 items.
Each entity contains 27 searchable field, which added to index in this way: new Field(key, value, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))

Now we have two search options:

1. Search only by 4 fields using fuzzy search
2. Search by 4-27 fields using exact search

We have a search service that every week automatically searches by about 53000 people such “Bob Huston”, “Sara Conor”, “Sujan Hong Uin Ho”, etc.

So we experience slow search speed in option **1**, it`s an average 4-8 sec in searcher.Search and it`s our major problem.

Search sample code:

```
                var index = FSDirectory.Open(indexPath);
                var searcher = new IndexSearcher(index, true);
                this.analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, new HashSet<string>())
                var queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, queryFields, this.analyzer);
                queryParser.AllowLeadingWildcard = false;
                Query query;
                query = queryParser.Parse(token);
                var results = searcher.Search(query, NumberOfResults);// NumberOfResults==500
```

Our fuzzy search query to find “bob cong hong” in 4 fields:

(((PersonFirstName:bob~0.6) OR (PersonLastName:bob~0.6) OR (PersonAliases:bob~0.6) OR (PersonAlternativeSpellings:bob~0.6)) AND ((PersonFirstName:cong~0.6) OR (PersonLastName:cong~0.6) OR (PersonAliases:cong~0.6) OR (PersonAlternativeSpellings:cong~0.6)) AND ((PersonFirstName:hong~0.6) OR (PersonLastName:hong~0.6) OR (PersonAliases:hong~0.6) OR (PersonAlternativeSpellings:hong~0.6)))

Current improvements:

1. We combined these 4 fields to 1 search field
2. We decided to use single IndexSearcher in service instead of open in every search request
3. MergeFactor=2

Total combination of improvements produces about **30-40% speed increasing**.

Following this [article](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed) we`ve made most of possible optimizations:

- Index is placed on SAS drive which is quite fast: http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=ie&l=en&s=dhs&cs=iedhs1&sku=400-AHWT#Overview
- We have enough RAM memory
- MergeFactor 2
- Tried to move index to RAMDirectory, but test results aren`t stable, sometimes speed is the same

Do you have other suggestions how to improve search speed in our situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the speed of Fuzzy Queries by setting their prefix length to a non-zero value.  This will allow lucene to narrow the set of possible results efficiently.  Like this:

```
queryParser.FuzzyPrefixLength = 2;
```

Also, it doesn't affect the query you've provided as an example, but if you care at all about performance, you should remove the line `queryParser.AllowLeadingWildcard = false;`.  Leading wildcards will absolutely kill performance.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just disable leading wildcards (queryParser.AllowLeadingWildcard = false), why should I remove this line?

Comment: `QueryParser` disallows leading wildcards (things like: `myField:*bar`) for a reason, they perform extremely poorly.